# I need to disable reverse path filtering in linux to set net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter to 0(net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2)

Tags: linux, ipv4

I need to disable reverse path filtering in Linux. I tried like this

```
 root@user:/home/user# sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=0
```

now I like to know how to make above settings active so reverse path filtering is disabled do I need to restart sysctl or some thing, Can anyone please tell this

I tried like above but when I ran the `sysctl -system`

I get this

net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter": Invalid argument

why this invalid argument message and I tried changing it to net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0 but it still printing sysctl -system as

```
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2
along with message
```

Comment: `--system` does NOT show you the "active" setting, but the setting that will be applied upon (re)boot. See the man page of `sysctl` for details. (Also the man page of `sysctl.d` to see how to override the vendor-shipped boot setting appropriately.)